# Integrate $\int \frac{x}{x^4+4}dx$

Tags: analysis, indefinite-integrals

I'm having trouble solving the integral

$\int \frac{x}{x^4+4}dx$

I already tried the following but, I'm getting stuck after step 3.

$\int \frac{x}{(x^2)^2+4}dx $

$u = x^2 , du = 2x dx, \frac{du}{2}=xdx$

$\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{u^2+4}du$

Comment: What you did is correct and what you ended up with is a standard anti derivative in the form of an artangent. That's got to be in your textbook

Comment: @projectilemotion yes I know that. But I have $ \int \frac{1}{u^2+4}du $

Comment: How about substituting $v=u/2$? You will get $\int \frac{dv}{v^2+1}$ multiplied by some factor, which you know how to compute.

Comment: Yes, the anti derivative is an arctangent.

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't want to use $\int \frac{1}{x^2+1}~dx=\arctan(x)+C$, you can just substitute $u=2\tan(\theta)$.

Comment: Every well-bred young people should know that $\;\displaystyle\int\frac{\mathrm d x}{x^2+a^2}=\frac1a\arctan\frac xa$.

Comment: The answer is correct provided an integration constant is added.

Answer (score 3):

Use $$\frac{x}{x^4+4}=\frac{x}{x^4+4x^2+4-4x^2}=\frac{x}{(x^2-2x+2)(x^2+2x+2)}=$$

$$=\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{x^2-2x+2}-\frac{1}{x^2+2x+2}\right)=\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{(x-1)^2+1}-\frac{1}{(x+1)^2+1}\right).$$

Comment: Can down-voter explain us, why did you do it?

Comment: Some men just want to watch the world burn.

Comment: Clever completion of squares - I expect nothing less from this man!

Comment: Clever, but this doesn't seem like it would help OP to solve the problem when they don't know how to integrate something of the form $1/(x^2+a^2)$.

Comment: @YiFan Are you sure? What do you think about the following? $\int\frac{1}{(x-1)^2+1^2}dx=\arctan(x-1)+C.$

Comment: I think if the OP knew how to integrate that, they would easily be able to see the $x\mapsto ax$ substitution which solves the general case. Probably the problem here is they don't even know how to integrate $1/(x^2+1)$. As with all things, I could be wrong, of course.

Comment: @YiFan Now you knows! By the way, he knew it yesterday.  But why you down-voted?

Comment: I didn't say I was the downvoter, did I?

Comment: @YiFan Yes, of course, you did'not say that you is not down-voter, did I?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from

$$\int \frac{x}{x^4+4}\,dx$$

Make the substitution $u=x^2$. Then, $\dfrac{du}{2}=x\,dx$ and the integral becomes

$$\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{u^2+4}\,du$$

Now let $u=2\tan(\theta)$. Then, $du=2\sec^2(\theta)\,d\theta$ and the integral becomes

$$\frac{1}{4}\int \frac{\sec^2(\theta)}{1+\tan^2{(\theta)}}\,d\theta$$

and since $1+\tan^2{(\theta)}=\sec^2(\theta)$, we may rewrite the integral as

$$\frac{1}{4}\int d\theta=\frac{1}{4}\theta+C$$

where $\theta=\arctan\left(\dfrac{u}{2}\right)$ and $u=x^2$, so we conclude that

$$\frac{1}{4}\theta+C=\frac{1}{4}\arctan\left(\frac{u}{2}\right)+C=\frac{1}{4}\arctan\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)+C$$

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int \frac{x}{x^4+4}dx= \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{dt}{4+t^2}=\frac{1}{2} \tan^{-1} t/2+C=\frac{1}{4} \tan^{-1} x^2/2+C$$ Here, we took $x^2=t \implies 2xdx=dt$